In React js unable to get waterfall chart using Highcharts library
I need to build a waterfall chart in my React js web application using Highcharts, I have installed highcharts and 'highcharts-react-official' but while doing below import:
import HighchartsWaterfall from 'highcharts/modules/waterfall';

I am getting error

Module not found: Can't resolve 'highcharts/modules/waterfall.

When I checked my node_modules folder under highcharts/modules I do not see any waterfall related library. I tried installing latest highcharts version still no luck.
How to fix this issue for React JS application?
I am expecting waterfall related files/libraries to be present under highcharts/modules folder post installing highcharts library.

Sadly the waterfall module does not exist. To solve the issue, you only need to import highcharts-more.
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

import HC_More from "highcharts/highcharts-more";

HC_More(Highcharts);

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/highcharts-react-simple-chart-forked-xwslcy

Thanks a lot !! It worked. @Dominik Chudy
